# pytest gives module not found error in mindsdb

Tags: pytest, modulenotfounderror, mindsdb

I was trying to fix [#5688 in mindsdb](https://github.com/mindsdb/mindsdb/issues/5688). I did the setup & recreated the issue by following the steps mentioned in the issue.
python -m pytest tests/ -> 17 errors
[initial error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q3am.png)

I referred to the official pytest documentation & numerous answers to similar questions on stack overflow, none proved fruitful to solve the issue.

For example: I added init.py file in tests folder -> reduces to 1 error: ModuleNotFoundError
[Module not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt7Up.png)
Initially I thought this error was an issue with my local setup & proceeded with the PR. The checks there caught the [same error](https://github.com/mindsdb/mindsdb/actions/runs/5004672484/jobs/9149118009#step:6:99) for a different file under tests folder (I'm guessing this is because the check is in Ubuntu; by the way my system is Windows).

This was the [expected fix as mentioned by mindsdb maintainer](https://github.com/mindsdb/mindsdb/pull/6166#discussion_r1209782842)

I also tried several suggestions for adding the directory to Python search path, which didn't help. By the way, Python search path already had the path to the required file.
[Python search paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouumF.png)

I'm totally out of options to try. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.